# There is way to change column value through Modify?

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

There is way to change column value through the Modify function?

Thanks

Comment: I don't expect so; Modify() is usually about changing the DataObject, not the data. Is there a reason why SetItem() or dot notation assignment isn't appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know to access the data via a DataWindow expression is through the `datawindow.data` property describe, but you  have only a read *only* access to the dw data globally without access to a specific row/column.

I think that you are looking for the `SetItem()` method. If you prefer the dotted notation, you can also use the `dw.object.data[row, col]`.

Comment: Looking at the help file (Contents \ DataWindow Reference \ DataWindow Object Properties \ Controls in a DW & their properties  \ Properties for the DataWindow object), I don't see "datawindow.data" marked as something that can be used with Modify () (an X in the M column). Are you mentioning this as read-only access, or do you have different experience with modifying data through this attribute?

Comment: @Terry Yes read only is what I meant with "but you have only a read access to the dw data". Maybe that I should have not mentioned it at all; I guess that the OP need is simple.